# Why does my localization cookie seem to not want to change?

Tags: php, cookies, localization, internationalization, logic

Why cant I change cookie?

If  you chose a language you cant change. You have to empty your cookies if you want to change language. Why is that?

```
if (isset($_GET['setLang']) && $_GET['setLang'] == 'en' 
|| isset($_COOKIE['setLang']) && $_COOKIE['setLang'] == 'en') {
setcookie("setLang", 'en', time()+(3600*12)); //expires in 12 hours
include('language/en/common.php');
}


elseif (isset($_GET['setLang']) && $_GET['setLang'] == 'se' 
|| isset($_COOKIE['setLang']) && $_COOKIE['setLang'] == 'se') {
setcookie("setLang", 'se', time()+(3600*12)); //expires in 12 hours
include('language/se/common.php');
}

else if (isset($_GET['setLang']) && $_GET['setLang'] == 'fr' 
|| isset($_COOKIE['setLang']) && $_COOKIE['setLang'] == 'fr') {
setcookie("setLang", 'fr', time()+(3600*12)); //expires in 12 hours
include('language/fr/common.php');
}

// default language is english
else {
  include('language/en/common.php');
}
```

Comment: Reading that logic hurt my brain :(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly can change cookies.  You can't change languages using the logic you have there because the way you've written it, an existing setting in `$_COOKIE` will *always* override a setting in `$_GET` (except for `en`, where `$_GET` will be checked first, so right now you should be able to switch to `en` if you started with another language).  You need to do all checks against `$_GET` first, then all checks against `$_COOKIE`, if you want to be able to change languages.

Comment: Or better yet, to make things clearer, pick one of the two locations as the "Canonical language source" and have all your language changing code based off of that one source alone. Then you have the other source override. E.g. make `$_GET` the canonical source, so you have a small blurb of `include`'s, and above that if `$_GET` is not present, have the cookie override and set `$_GET` with its default contents.

Answer (score 2):

The logic hurt my brain, too.

```
$language = $_GET['setLang'] || $_COOKIE['setLang']) || 'en';
setcookie("setLang", $language, time()+(3600*12));
include('language/' . $language . '/common.php');
```

Should achieve the same effect and fix your cookie issues (untested, though).

Comment: Please dont do that.

At least have a list of allowed language codes and validate against this, before blindly trusting input from user and using that in an include.

Comment: (Well, actually, since the last term is `'en'`, `$language` will always be `true`.)

Answer (score 0):

> setcookie() defines a cookie to be
> sent along with the rest of the HTTP
> headers. Like other headers, cookies
> must be sent before any output from
> your script (this is a protocol
> restriction). This requires that you
> place calls to this function prior to
> any output, including  and
>
> tags as well as any whitespace.

https://www.php.net/setcookie